# Focus all Finder windows simultaneaously

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, finder

Does OSX (10.7.5) have a (keyboard) shortcut to focus all Finder windows simultaneously?

Obviously it's impossible to focus more than one window. What I mean to ask was, how does one get multiple windows of a single application in the foreground.

Let's say a Finder window is the 'top' window, 'below' that is a Chrome window, below that two more Finder windows (picture one). What I want is to put all Finder windows in the foreground (picture 2).

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you're already in Finder:

  Use ⌘⇥ to switch to another application and then use ⌘⇥ to switch back to Finder again.
- If you're not already in Finder:

  Use ⌘⇥ to switch to Finder. All of its windows will be brought to the foreground.

To give an example: Before, Finder is active. I press ⌘⇥ to switch to Chrome, and then once again to switch back to Finder. All windows are brought to the foreground:

[image]

[image]

Comment: See my answer. You simply ⌘⇥ back to Finder to get all of its windows in the foreground.

Comment: Not sure why I have never noticed this behaviour... Also, I just found out, clicking an Application in the Dock, shows all windows!

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to 'focus' all windows at once, since by design only one window at a time can have focus, but there is a keyboard shortcut to change focus between windows of the same application. The keyboard shortcut is ⌘ + ` (Command + Grave)